# What is the better way to select minimum value within join?

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance

I've three tables where I want to select the oldest media according to date from a joined table. The query is working fine but I want to know if its correct solution for performance or there is a better way to do this.

```
SELECT product.`product_id`, product.`title`, product.`price`, 
media_gallery.`thumbnail`, product.`special_price` 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT product_media.`product_id`, product_media.`media_id` 
FROM product_media ORDER BY product_media.`added_on` ASC LIMIT 1) product_media 
ON product.`product_id` = product_media.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN media_gallery ON product_media.`media_id` = media_gallery.`media_id` 
GROUP BY product.`product_id` 
LIMIT 10
```

I've three tables from which I want to select the products with single image and the image should be the oldest. The image is stored in media_gallery and the image is assigned in product_media. The product can have multiple images  which are referenced in product_media. I want to select product_id, product.title, product.price, product.special_price, media_gallery.thumbnail. The thumbnail should be the image added as earliest

```
CREATE TABLE `product_media` (
  `id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `media_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_id_2` (`product_id`,`media_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `media_id` (`media_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_media_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `product_media_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES `media_gallery` (`media_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `media_gallery` (
  `media_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `media_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `media_title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `special_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) DEFAULT 'AVAILABLE',
  `weight` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `unit_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sku` (`sku`),
  KEY `unit_id` (`unit_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_id`) REFERENCES `units` (`unit_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Your `SELECT` clause is invalid because it includes non aggregate columns.

Comment: the use of group by without aggregation function is deprecated in SQL and not allowed is the more recente mysql  version .. you are not selecting the minimun value (you have not a MIN(column_name) function  .. you are select the fist 10 order rows .. this is not the same

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I do it correctly?

Comment: To be honest, without seeing table structure and some sample data, I would just be guessing at best if I were to suggest something.

Comment: hmm I'm posting the table structure and the sample data

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've modified the question. Please help. thanks :)

Comment: The inner query delivers at most _one_ `product_id` and `media_id`, correct?  Those columns are UNIQUE in their tables, correct?  Therefore the `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT 10` will never fetch more than _one_ row, correct?  And that is what you want - only _one_ row?

Comment: @RickJames You are absolutely right and I'm already doing that for now but I want to get the result based on timestamp that is older. Thanks for your answer :)